# onCreateDialog doesn't refresh message

Tags: android

I try to create AlertDialog. It works but setMessage doesn't refresh message. Code snippet below:

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        super.onCreateDialog(id);
        switch (id) {
           case CONFIRM:                    
                confirmView = new LinearLayout(this);

                return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                        .setView(confirmView)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setTitle("The WiFi")                      
                        .setMessage(infoMsg);
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                Functionality.StartWiFiManager(ControllerService.this);
                            }
                        })                         
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {                            
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                                    
                            }
                        })
                        .create();  
       }
}
```

Invoking:

```
infoMsg = "My message";     
showDialog(CONFIRM);
```

So when I change my infoMsg and invoke showDialog again, the message is the same.
What am I doing wrong? Please, help me.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use 'onPrepareDialog' to reset information that changes every time the dialog is shown. [onCreateDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) is only called once, then the dialog is held onto and re-used. [onPrepareDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog,%20android.os.Bundle%29) is called every time that the dialog is shown.

Of course, both onCreateDialog and onPrepareDialog are deprecated and you are supposed to be using 'DialogFragment' class and the 'FragmentManager' instead. But if you (like me) are continuing to use the old APIs, then onPrepareDialog is what you want.

Comment: I've tried it already! I removed setMessage from the onCreateDialog and placed this one into onPrepareDialog like below:                     @Override
  protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
      switch (id) {
          case CONFIRM:
              ((AlertDialog)dialog).setMessage(infoMsg);              
              break;
      }
  }                                                               But it doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, call `removeDialog` after done with `Dialog`

Answer (score 2):

In the documenation for `protected Dialog onCreateDialog (int id, Bundle args)` it says:

> If you use `showDialog(int)`, the activity will call through to this method the first time, and hang onto it thereafter. Any dialog that is created by this method will automatically be saved and restored for you, including whether it is showing.
>
> If you would like the activity to manage saving and restoring dialogs for you, you should override this method and handle any ids that are passed to `showDialog(int)`.

So it looks that the dialog will only be created one, after that android will save/restore it.

Comment: They should emphasize "the activity will call through to this method the first time ONLY", I always find that their documentation is confusing. xD

Answer (score 1):

It's Better not to use either `onCreateDialog()` for creating  `Diaog` and then use `onPrepareDialog()` for any refreshment or update of data when `Dialog` is again clicked.For these methods you dont have much control over your `Dialog`,and it will increase your code complexity and lengthy and normally very difficult to understand. for this you can create your own customize layout in `xml` and you have Diaplay it in your dialog.only you have to write a method.no need to write `onPrepareDialog()` for refreshing of data.
here is simple example of customize `Dialog`.

Here Your Dialog contain a input textfields with with buttons name **ok** and **cancel**.

mydialog.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/myInput"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="warp_content"/>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/okButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"/>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="cancel"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Then You have to write only your Dialog method

```
AlertDialog dialog;
public void myDialog(){

AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Dialog Demo");
LayoutInflater inflater=getLAyoutInflater();
final View dialogView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.myDialog,null);
builder.setView(dialogView);
dialog=builder.create();
dialog.show();
}
```

use this method any where as a dialog so simple.